# How do I have a popup for multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to have a popup for each news article in my database, so that the user can edit it.  I can make it work for a single news article, but when I try to use .next() to find the next popup after the link it doesn't work.  Seems like I'm misunderstanding something here?

php to make the links & popups:

```
  foreach ($news as $n) {
//clickable link
         echo '<a class="trigger_popup">'.$n['fldSubject'].'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit edit-file clickable">&nbsp;</span></a>';
//hidden div
         echo '<div class="hover_bkgr"><span class="helper"></span><div><div class="popupCloseButton">&times;</div>'.$n['fldBody'].'</div></div>'
}
```

JQuery

```js
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.trigger_popup').click(function(){
       $(this).next('.hover_bkgr').show();
    });
    $('.hover_bkgr').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.hover_bkgr').hide();
    });
    $('.popupCloseButton').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.hover_bkgr').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.hover_bkgr{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10;
}
.hover_bkgr .helper{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.hover_bkgr > div {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 60px #555;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 15px 5%;
}
.popupCloseButton {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #999;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    right: -20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.popupCloseButton:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.trigger_popup {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
}
.trigger_popup:hover{
    color:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: can you show us your rendered html source code on specific page (for example couple of news articles) + all js code that you have for that.. that way it's easier to debug it

Comment: unfortunately the rendered page is behind a login